# Modifying variable is not remembered in while-loop

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

I try to ask people about which interface use as public interface on iptables:
The while-loop seams not to remember the variable, i really don't know why.

```
  #!/bin/sh
### Show all available interfaces and configure to use them in while-loop:
# Here is the answer of the function: 
# "${PUB_IF}" != "eth0" -a "${PUB_IF}" != "eth1" -a "${PUB_IF}" != "vmbr0"
function good_interfaces() {
ip a | grep '^[0-9]:' | grep -v 'lo' | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/:$/"/' -e '/$/ i\-a "${PUB_IF}" !=' | sed '$!N; s/\n/ /g' | tr '\n' ' ' | awk 'sub("^...", "")'
}

### Show available interfaces
# Here is the answer of "echo ${IF_LIST}"
# eth0? eth1? vmbr0?
IF_LIST=$(ip a | grep '^[0-9]:' | grep -v 'lo' | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/:/\?/g' | tr '\n' ' ')

while [ $(good_interfaces) ]; do
# When i replace $(good_interfaces) by its answer, the loop works: 
# while [ "${PUB_IF}" != "eth0" -a "${PUB_IF}" != "eth1" -a "${PUB_IF}" != "vmbr0" ] --> without the variable it works but isn't personalized for all machines
  echo "${IF_LIST}"
  read -p "Enter the interface to use: " PUB_IF
done;
```

Here is the `ip a` answer:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master vmbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet x.x.x.x/x brd x.x.x.x scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The sequence `grep … | grep -v … | awk … | sed …` should be a single command — probably `awk` but the chances are these days you could use `sed` or `grep` instead.  There's no need for the four commands in a row, at any rate.  Even without that, you can put the sequence into a function so that you don't have to repeat yourself.  This would then leave us with a chance of understanding your question.  I assume the `unset PIB_IF` is not present in the original code.  If it is, the `-z "${PUB_IF}"` test is superfluous — it is unset so always counts as zero length.

Comment: The normal reason for a variable set in a loop not being remembered after the loop is that the loop is run in a sub-shell.  That isn't self-evidently the problem in the code shown.  Can you show three or four lines of output from `ip a` — one for the `lo` interface and at least two others so those of us without the `ip` command on their machine can see what the data you're processing looks like?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I modified the code with functions.
So you think that if I modify the sequence `grep... | sed... | awk...` in only one command it would works? The problem is from the pipe? I'm working on a single command for the sequence.
The unset PUB_IF is not present in the code, i'm testing the code directly in the shell, so i have to unset my variable.

Answer (score 0):

First some comments on your code:

- `#!/bin/sh`
  Removing the spaces on this line (and use bash). Now the line is only comment
- `ip a | grep '^[0-9]:' | grep -v 'lo' | a lot more`
  I am sorry, the command is getting to complicated. Do you think you can understand it yourself over two months when you do not see the input?
- `IF_LIST=$(ip a | grep '^[0-9]:' | grep -v 'lo' | and more)`
  Some code is shared with the function good_interfaces
- `while [ $(good_interfaces) ]; do`
  A while loop wants a true/false expression, you are hoping that the string returned by your function will be seen as a expression.

So how should you implement a construction for reading a PUB_IF and breaking when valid?

put all valid interfaces in a string with clear delimiters (i will use spaces).
I will add a space before and after the string, for easy matching later.
Ask for a PUB_IF and check.

```
valid_interfaces=" eth0 eth1 vmbr0 "
PUB_IF=""
# Edit: changed "while [ true ]; do" into "while true; do"
while true; do
   read -p "Enter the interface to use: " PUB_IF
   if [[ "${valid_interfaces}" = *;${PUB_IF};* ]]; then
      echo "${PUB_IF} is valid"
      break
   else
      echo "Nope, please enter something like${valid_interfaces}"
   fi
done
```

Another question is how to find the valid interfaces. Use cut:

```
valid_interfaces=" $(ip a | grep ": <" | grep -v "lo" | cut -d: -f2 | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Comment: You want `while true; do` instead of `while [ true ]; do`. Even though they are functionally equivalent, `[ true ]` is true because the string in brackets is not empty, not because it's running the `true` command.

Comment: @Glenn Thanks, so true. Even `while [ false ]` is true.

Comment: @Walter Thanks!! You're right, I really don't know how I only focused on that method. Your's is so much easier!!
So it's impossible to put a function in a while loop because while won't see it as an expression? Nothing can solve this 'problem'?
I tried you're code and the part `if [[ "${valid_interfaces}" = *;${PUB_IF};* ]]; then` doesn't work on my machine. Here's the result: `sh test;    
Enter the interface to use: eth    
test: 6: test: [[: not found    
test: 6: test: eth: not found    
eth is valid`

Comment: @Walter, I finally used your construction: `while [ -z $i ]; do
   read -p "Enter the interface to use ($valid_interfaces): " PUB_IF;
   for if in ${valid_interfaces}; do
   [ "${if}" = ${PUB_IF} ] && { i=1; break; }; 
done; done`

Comment: Does the test on `${PUB_IF}` work when you just hit enter on the `read -p`? To be sure, use `"${PUB_IF}"`. I didn't in my code, but I was using `[[ .. ]]` which works different then `[ .. ]`. When your solution works, you can accept this answer.